# How to get admin access token for Realm on EC2

Tags: swift, amazon-ec2, realm

I'm trying to get the admin access token for my realm hosted on EC2. I've seen instructions in the documentation and in various posts here but I can't get it to work. Here's what I've tried:

- I do have a `admin_token.base64` file. I've copied its contents into the access token field of both "Connect to Object Server" in the Realm Browser and I get `Failed to connect to Object Server, io.realm.sync error 5`, followed by `Failed to connect to Object Server, Check the URL and that the server is accessible.`
  I am able to get to the realm using my username and password so the URL is right and the server is accessible.
- I run `realm-generate-admin-token` but I get `[ERROR] Could not find private key at /etc/realm/token-signature.key'.` I'm pretty stuck here; I'm doing this on macOS and isn't this a Linux address it's looking for? 
  I'm guessing this has something to do with the pointers in my `configuration.yml` file? Is this about my EC2 keypairs? I have the Access Key, the Private Key, the keypair, all in the location that `configuration.yml` points to. I think.

Is it that I'm running the `realm-generate-admin-token` on my local machine instead of on the server or something?

I am clearly stuck and clueless. Please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just run through this scenario of using the admin token to login with the Realm Browser and it worked with the latest version of Realm Object Server.

In your case, regenerating the token might be necessary, but you need to do this on the server, using the `realm-generate-admin-token` command.  When it's done, you should be able to use the contents of `/etc/realm/admin_token.base64` in the Realm Browser.